# hide iframe if result is 404 http error (with .cgi source)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want display multi iframe in html page, but if result is 404 http error, i do not want display this iframe (`$("#iframe").attr("height", "480");`). I accept all solution (**CAUTION: cross domain error**).

My sample display 3 iframes (1st is dynamic and is my subject of this post) 2n is good url and 3th is wrong url (http 404).

**Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="iframe" src="" width="0" height="0"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.20:81/script.cgi" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.21:81/script.cgi" width="640" height="480"></iframe>

<script>
$(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.21:81/script.cgi",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function () {
                $("#iframe").attr("src", "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.21:81/script.cgi");
                $("#iframe").attr("width", "640");
                $("#iframe").attr("height", "480");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I try other solution but do not works:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="" width="0" height="0"></iframe>

<script>
    $("#iframe").attr("src", "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.21:81/script.cgi");
    if($("#iframe").contents().find("body").length) {
        $("#iframe").attr("width", "640");
        $("#iframe").attr("height", "480");
    }
</script>
```

I try remove `dataType: "jsonp",` but do not works:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: Unless those external resources are CORS-enabled, this won’t be possible using client-side code only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to hide div if result is 404 http error

```js
$(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=tgbNymZ7vqY",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function () {
                $("#iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY");
                $("#iframe").attr("width", "640");
                $("#iframe").attr("height", "480");
            },
            error: function (xhr, responseText) {
                if (xhr.status == 404) {
                 console.log(xhr.status)
                    $("#iframe").hide();
                }

            }

        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="iframe" src="" width="0" height="0"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.20:81/script.cgi" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.21:81/script.cgi" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Comment: I have updated my code check youtube video it is working. you can check if any problems please let me know.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY is not a cgi video. try with this http://202.151.80.20:81/anony/mjpg.cgi

Comment: did you find a solution to get the status of the error?

Comment: Sorry, I try but did not find the solution.When I try the wrong URL got an error but I do not catch error but when URL is ok then it's giving timeout error. I already ask this in StackOverflow but did not find correct answerer.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49694794/how-to-catch-error-neterr-aborted