# How to catch error net::ERR_ABORTED

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to catch error net::ERR_ABORTED in ajax. This is my code

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://example.com",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   jsonp: "callback",
   timeout: 5000,
   success: function () {
   },
   error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   }
})
```

In console I get this error

`jquery.js:9679 GET http://example.com/?callback=jQuery33102519970992725571_1523023091094&_=1523023091095 net::ERR_ABORTED`

I have tried `Try catch` but I cannot get any error.is there any way how I can catch this error. I need `cross-domain access` too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you could use `fail()` as such

```
const request = $.ajax({ //your code })

request.fail((jqXHR, textStatus) => {
  console.log(textStatus);
});
```

[fail in jQuery's docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-longdesc)